# How to fetch apk file to a folder from another app?

Tags: java, android

```
I am trying to copy apk of the user installed apps in a folder.
Here is the code

 public void backUpApk(int position){
        FileChannel inputChannel = null;
        FileChannel outputChannel = null;
        try{

            App app = getItem(position);
            System.out.println("Source "+app.getApplicationInfo().sourceDir+File.separator+app.getLabel()+".apk");
            File source = new File(app.getApplicationInfo().sourceDir+File.separator+app.getLabel()+".apk");
            inputChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+ Constants.FOLDER_NAME);
            outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
            outputChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel,0,inputChannel.size());

        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Its throwing NoReadableChannel exception. How to accomplish this task??
Can I copy apk from system directory like this or not?

Comment: add `if (source.exists())` and see what happens

Comment: Ya source exists. @MJafar Mash

Comment: and `source.canRead()` ?

Comment: I was not giving file name for output channel, I had to do like this 
 File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+ Constants.FOLDER_NAME+File.separator+APK_NAME;
That I was not giving.